# Swagger Response Examples .Net 5 are not displayed

Tags: swagger, middleware, .net-5

After updating my .net core 2.1 project to .net-5 and swagger swashbuckle from 2 to 5.6.3 the swagger response examples are not getting displayed anymore. Is there a new best practice way on how to solve this problem?

On 2.1 i have added some definitions on top of my controller.

```
 [SwaggerResponse(409, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<ErrorObjects>))]
 [SwaggerResponseExample(409, typeof(MethodResponseErrors))]
```

And in addition to this i implemented the MethodResponseErrors like this:

```
public class MethodResponseErrors : IExamplesProvider<List<ErrorObjects>>
{
    List<ErrorObjects> IExamplesProvider<List<ErrorObjects>>.GetExamples()
    {
        return new List<ErrorObjects>
        {
            new Error1(),
            new Error2(),
            new Error3()
        };
    }
}
```

After this my response examples got displayed.

Comment: same issue here.. it is just not working, my attributes are ignored